# Что блокирует выполнение глобального события mousemove при событий mousedown на IMG?

Tags: javascript, события, отладка

Тестируя код в фаерфоксе 82.0.2 столкнулся с такой вот делимой. Что перестаёт отрабатывать событие.
Думаю, что это не баг браузира. ))) Может кто знает что это и как это лечить.

```
<body>
    <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/ubQRU.jpg" alt="IMG">
    <script type="text/javascript">
        document.addEventListener("mousemove", function(){console.log("test")}, false)
    </script>
</body>
```

**P.S.** Событии mousemove перестаёт отрабатывать на 3 пикселе mousedown в любую сторону, после событие mouseup, mousemove работает как "ни в чём не бывало".

```js
document.addEventListener("mousemove", function(){console.log("test")}, false)
```

```html
<img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/ubQRU.jpgg" alt="IMG">
```

Comment: Firefox во многом странно себя ведёт, в отличии от других браузеров

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Необходимо отменить событие `dragstart`.

```js
document.addEventListener("mousemove", function(){console.log("test")}, false)          
document.addEventListener("dragstart", function(e){e.preventDefault()}, false)
```

```html
<img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/ubQRU.jpgg" alt="IMG">
```